# CORS was working fine but suddenly stopped working?

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

This is what I have in Node:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200/');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

My front-end is in Angular. Everything was working just fine, but all of a sudden I started getting CORS errors. When I check the console, I get this:

[image]

The Initiator Context and the Allowed Origin are exactly the same. And, as I mentioned before, I was having 0 issues until all of a sudden it decided to stop working. So I don't understand what's going on here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess that you modified something in the request itself as sent from the client and that request now requires [pre-flight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) with an OPTIONS request.  Show us the details of the client request and we can help more with that.  You can unintentionally change a request from not requiring pre-flight to requiring pre-flight by just changing the content-type or adding a custom header or any one of several other types of changes.

Comment: Can you add server/app.js file,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `http://localhost:4200`, without the last '/'

Comment: Well, it's always the stupidest mistakes isn't it? I could've sworn I did it like that once and it didn't work, but now it did. Thanks!